# How to fix golang sql string conversion scan error

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

I'm receiving the following error when querying a row in an sqlite3 database:

`sql: Scan error on column index 3: converting string "" to a int64: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax`

The query itself works, as it is able to return the queried data. I should note that each row in the database contains several columns with NULL data (only the `Id` and `Email` columns are populated). I am struggling to understand why the err occurs and how to resolve it.

The SQL table has the following nine columns:

```
`0,Id,INTEGER,0,,1
1,Email,TEXT,0,,0
2,Name,TEXT,0,,0
3,Rsvp,INTEGER,0,,0
4,Guests,INTEGER,0,,0
5,Meal0,INTEGER,0,,0
6,Meal1,INTEGER,0,,0
7,Comments,TEXT,0,,0
8,ModifiedAt,TEXT,0,,0`
```

which are defined in server.go with the following struct (I added the sql.NullString to handle the empty columns):

```
type User struct {
    Id         int
    Email      string
    Name       sql.NullString
    Rsvp       sql.NullInt64
    Guests     sql.NullInt64
    Meal0      sql.NullInt64
    Meal1      sql.NullInt64
    Comments   sql.NullString
    ModifiedAt sql.NullString
}
```

the query is from the following handler:

```
func Rsvp1Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  email := r.URL.Path[len("/rsvp/"):]
  var user User
  err := userStatement.QueryRow(email).Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Name, &user.Rsvp, &user.Guests, &user.Meal0, &user.Meal1, &user.Comments, &user.ModifiedAt)

  switch {
  case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
    log.Println("No user with that ID.")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Email address not found: %s", email)

  case err != nil:
    log.Println(err)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Database error:\n", err)
  default:
    log.Println("Query success. Email address: ", email)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&user)
}
```

which relies on the following constant and var:

```
const userSelect  = "SELECT * FROM rsvp WHERE email = ?"
var userStatement   *sql.Stmt
```

Any help or insight into the error is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try being explicit in your SQL SELECT statement instead of using `*`. This will help rule out a column mismatch.

Comment: I've made the SQL SELECT explicit, but still receive the same error: `sql: Scan error on column index 3: converting string "" to a int64: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems one of your columns (most likely `Rsvp`) is stored as a string type not int and it's set to `""` instead of `null`.

So you either have to change `Rsvp` (might be a different column) to `sql.NullString`, redo the database to have nulls instead of empty strings for numeric fields or if you believe it's a bug in the driver, open an issue on their tracker.